# vscode path file auto-complete has stopped working

Tags: autocomplete, path, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am using VScode (version 1.20, windows 10). Path file Auto-complete has stopped working around the time I upgraded from 1.19 to 1.20. When I enter "ctrl+space", I just get what seems to be a random list of words. Here is a screenshot of what I get:

[image]

I add a look at this  [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/23962). But the solution proposed (user settings **editor.quickSuggestions**) did not work in my case. Is this a bug in the 1.20 version? I downgraded to 1.19. Still the problem remains.

If any one could give me a hint, or a solution, how would be very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this drove me crazy until I realised I didn't have the project folder open in explorer, only the file. That should be all you need.